# How to dynamically add a div in between Divs

Tags: jquery

I have a series of DIV tags in my static page. While loading the page, based on business rules, I need to embed a DIV tag dynamically in between the tags.

**Note**: The requirement is is not to add it as a hidden during design and show it based on the business rule.

My HTML,

```
    <div class="header">
        <div class="titles-bar">
            <div id="dvDynamicHeader">
                <div id="mainTabsGroups1" data-enhance="false">
                    <ul class="tabs left">
                        <li class="current" id="tabCustomers"><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
<!--Dynamic div-->
                <div id="mainTabsGroups2" data-enhance="false">
                    <ul class="tabs left">
                        <li><a id="tabBusinessUnits" href="#">Business Units</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
<!--End of Dynamic div-->
                <div id="mainTabsGroups3" data-enhance="false">
                    <ul class="tabs left">
                        <li class="current" id="tabCustomers"><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a id="tabApplications" href="#">Applications</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far.. read on [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: but at which position or after which div you want to add new div?

Comment: can we see your HTML and JS code?

Comment: @Agramer... Got it tq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it anywhere on the page on the load and then within the `$(document).ready()` use the jQuery `insertAfter()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#insertedDiv).insertAfter("#firstDiv");
});
```

**NOTE:** It doesn't matter if it's hidden or not as the function will fire at the very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I think [jQuery after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) is what you're looking for. You can add elements/textafter elements matched by a given selector.

```js
$(".insertAfterMe").after("<div>Inserted DIV</div>");
```

```css
div {
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="insertAfterMe">Hello</div>
  <div>Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12796915)

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, I agree and updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback.